# Running gdb from command line gives Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize

Tags: python, gcc, gdb

Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit
Trying to run gdb from a terminal window gives:

> gdb
>   Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/**init**.py", line 123
>       raise CodecRegistryError,\
>                               ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I have seen the same error for other command line commands and I also get if I mistype a command. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Additional Info: setting >export PYTHONPATH= or > export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages allows gdb to run, but > export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7 (which is what I expect) causes error